# Where statement with two criteria SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have got pretty much everything in order apart from the last statement.

I am hoping for the query to narrow down my searches further and place a statement that says if one of the records within agencyprofilesetupcomplete is 0 then look to see if the date in agencyprofilecreateddate is less than 90 days of todays date, if it is I want to also include those results.

```
select 
    distinct agencyprofilename, 
    (select 
         top 1 agencypayperiodfinalisestate 
     from 
       agencypayperiod as app 
     where 
       app.agencyprofileid = ap.agencyprofileid 
     order by 
       agencypayperiodpaydate)as 'Pay Period Finalise State', 
     agencyprofilecreateddate, agencyprofilesetupcomplete, 
     agencyemployertaxoffice

from 
    Agencyprofile as ap

left join 
   agencypayperiod as app on ap.agencyprofileid = app.agencyprofileid
left outer join 
   agencyemployer as ae on ap.agencyemployerid = ae.agencyemployerid
where agencypayperiodfinalisestate <>0
   and agencyemployertaxoffice is not null
   and agencyemployertaxoffice <>''
   or (agencyprofilesetupcomplete = 0 and agencyprofilecreateddate >= 
           (GetDate()-90))
order by agencyprofilename
```

I'm also using Microsoft SQL Server if you need to know.

Comment: Are you getting any error with this query?.

Comment: I think you want `agencyprofilecreateddate < (GetDate()-90` If I'm reading your criteria correctly.

Comment: What's your question? Are you getting data you don't want, or not getting data you do?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do would be *really* helpful.

Comment: Simplify this `agencyemployertaxoffice is not null
and agencyemployertaxoffice <>''` to `ISNULL(agencyemployertaxoffice,'') <> ''`

Comment: No errors, but if I remove the Or statement I'm returned with 262 rows and with the Or statement I get 283, whereas I should be getting fewer records as I want to further narrow down my results with the addition. It's probably not meant to be an Or

Comment: @WEI_DBA even better would be agencyemployertaxoffice > ''. This satisfies both conditions AND it is still sargable.

Comment: @jufg: Of course you get more rows. If you say "I want only rows that match condition x" you get less rows than with "I want only rows that match condition x or y", because you add all rows not matching x but matching y to the results. (And as `AND` has precedence over `OR` you actually say: "give me rows that either match the first three conditions or the last two.) If you want to narrow down the current results, you'll add `AND <additional condition>` instead.

Comment: BTW: Your outer joins don't seem to make sense and your `WHERE` clause renders them inner joins anyway. Only use outer joins when you really need them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try by grouping your first group of condition. For example

```
SELECT DISTINCT agencyprofilename
    ,(
        SELECT TOP 1 agencypayperiodfinalisestate
        FROM agencypayperiod AS app
        WHERE app.agencyprofileid = ap.agencyprofileid
        ORDER BY agencypayperiodpaydate
        ) AS 'Pay Period Finalise State'
    ,agencyprofilecreateddate
    ,agencyprofilesetupcomplete
    ,agencyemployertaxoffice
FROM Agencyprofile AS ap
LEFT JOIN agencypayperiod AS app ON ap.agencyprofileid = app.agencyprofileid
LEFT OUTER JOIN agencyemployer AS ae ON ap.agencyemployerid = ae.agencyemployerid
WHERE (
        agencypayperiodfinalisestate <> 0
        AND agencyemployertaxoffice IS NOT NULL
        AND agencyemployertaxoffice <> ''
        )
    OR (
        agencyprofilesetupcomplete = 0
        AND agencyprofilecreateddate < DATEADD(dd,1,(GetDate() - 90))
        )
ORDER BY agencyprofilename
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tweak on your date compare in the `WHERE` Clause...

You need to use `DATEADD function on your GETDATE() - 90.`

```
... >= DATEADD(dd, -90, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query.

I did not get a chance to test this. Let me know if you face any issues.

```
select 
    distinct agencyprofilename, 
    (select 
         top 1 agencypayperiodfinalisestate 
     from 
       agencypayperiod as app 
     where 
       app.agencyprofileid = ap.agencyprofileid 
     order by 
       agencypayperiodpaydate)as 'Pay Period Finalise State', 
     agencyprofilecreateddate, agencyprofilesetupcomplete, 
     agencyemployertaxoffice

from 
    Agencyprofile as ap

left join 
   agencypayperiod as app on ap.agencyprofileid = app.agencyprofileid
left outer join 
   agencyemployer as ae on ap.agencyemployerid = ae.agencyemployerid
where agencypayperiodfinalisestate <>0
   and IsNull(agencyemployertaxoffice,'') != ''
   or (agencyprofilesetupcomplete = 0 and agencyprofilecreateddate < DATEADD(dd,1,(GetDate() - 90))
order by agencyprofilename
```